# Javascript in Safari Plugin - download binary file data from XHR then resubmit

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to write a Safari Extension to grab the PDF document that the user has open and then submit it to another site via POST.

I've made this work in Chrome but copying the same method doesn't work because Safari doesn't work with `BlobBuilder`.

This is what works in Chrome:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", tab.url, true);

    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)  {

            var bb = new BlobBuilder();
            bb.append(this.response); 

            var blob = bb.getBlob('application/pdf');

            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

            http.open("POST", send_url, true);

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("src", blob);
            http.send(formData);
        }
```

The resulting POST talks to my PHP script and in its $_FILES array is my file. Perfect.

But absolutely nothing I try seems to work using Safari. I tried `responseType='blob'` to start with, but that didn't work. I can't get any of the Safari JS file objects to work with this data. I tried changing it to a Uint8 array but this didn't submit the data, just the string saying `"[object UInt8Array]"`

Any ideas?

Cheers!
Tony

Answer (score 2):

I got great results keeping responseType as 'arraybuffer' and then passing xhr.response into the constructor of a new Uint8Array worked perfectly in Safari 5.1.1 on my Mac:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        buffer = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
        for (var loop=0; loop<buffer.length; loop++) {
            // Do something with buffer[loop]
        }
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'yourfilename.here', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.send();
```

I must admit, I tried 'one or two' things before RTFM mode kicked in and I found that the [MDN page on XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Receiving_binary_data_using_JavaScript_typed_arrays) had a section on reading binary data (MDN is a great resource).

Once I put that in place, everything started working fantastically.

Dan

Comment: Did you really get Safari to upload binary data? Adding an `ArrayBuffer` to a `FormData` object causes it to submit a malformed multipart form, so the server reports the entire file contents as `------WebKitFormBoundaryaiKF2ZGx25JiZdKY--`. But that's more than has happened with any other attempts, where Safari has quietly sent nothing.